# How to delete alternate nodes in a doubly linked list in C?

Tags: c, doubly-linked-list

I wrote the following code but it stops working after executing the create() function. I want to delete alternate elements starting from the head node. Is my delete_Alt() function correct? Please tell me where am I wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// using a structure
typedef struct mynode {
    int data;
    struct mynode *prev;    // to point to previous node
    struct mynode *link;    // to point to next node
} node;
node *head = NULL;

// creating the list
void create() {
    node *p, *q;
    int ch;
    do {
        p = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
        printf("enter data\n"); 
        scanf("%d", &p->data);
        if (head == NULL) 
        {
            p->prev = head;
            q = p;
        }
        else
        {
            p->prev = q;
            p->link = NULL;
            q->link = p;
            q = p;
        }
        printf("create another node?, press 1   ");
        scanf ("%d",&ch);
    } while(ch==1);
}

//to delete alternate elements
void delete_Alt() {
    if (head == NULL)
        printf("Empty list...ERROR");

    node *previous, *current, *next;    
    previous = head;
    current = head->link;
    while (previous !=NULL && current != NULL) {
        previous->prev = current->prev;
        previous->link = current->link; 

        next = current->link;
        previous->link = next;
        next->prev = previous;

        free(current);
    }
}

// print the list
void display() {
    node *temp;
    temp = head;
    while (temp != NULL) {
        printf("%d  ",temp->data);
        temp = temp->link;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main() {
    node *head = NULL;
    create();
    printf("List before deleting is:    ");
    display();
    delete_Alt();
    printf("List after deleting is:     ");
    display();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Think about the value of `current` (the address it contains) in the lifetime of your `while` loop. You set it *once*, before the loop. It is never changed again, yet it is both dereferenced and `free`'d  repeatedly. That can't *possibly* be right. It is also highly suspicious that, if the initial node pointed to by `head` is the first to be freed, why does the address held in `head` never change? An *expected* input/output sample would do this question, btw.

Answer (score 2):

you are doing some minor mistakes in create as well as in delete function...

Here is the updated code try it...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// using a structure
typedef struct mynode {
    int data;
    struct mynode *prev;    // to point to previous node
    struct mynode *link;    // to point to next node
} node;
node *head = NULL;

// creating the list
void create() {
    node *p, *q;
    int ch;
    do {
        p = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
        printf("enter data\n"); 
        scanf("%d", &p->data);
        p->link = NULL;
        if (head == NULL) 
        {
            p->prev = NULL;
            head = p;
        }
        else
        {
            q = head;
            while (q->link != NULL)
            q = q->link;
            p->prev = q;
            q->link = p;
        }
        printf("create another node?, press 1   ");
        scanf ("%d",&ch);
    } while(ch==1);
}

//to delete alternate elements
void delete_Alt() {
    if (head == NULL)
        printf("Empty list...ERROR");

    node *previous, *current, *next;    
    previous = head;
    current = head->link;
    while (previous !=NULL && current != NULL) 
    {
        previous->link = current->link; 
        next = current->link;
        free(current);
        if(next) 
        {
            next->prev = previous;
            current = next->link;
        }
        else 
        current = NULL;
        previous = next;
    }
}

// print the list
void display() {
    node *temp;
    temp = head;
    while (temp != NULL) {
        printf("%d  ",temp->data);
        temp = temp->link;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main() {
    node *head = NULL;
    create();
    printf("List before deleting is:    ");
    display();
    delete_Alt();
    printf("List after deleting is:     ");
    display();
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your program, you assigned a value to head only once:

```
node *head = NULL;
```

Then its value doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

You never assigned "head" to the first created element in the list. Therefore it is always null. Try this:

```
if (head == NULL) 
{
  p->prev = head;
  head = p;      
  q = p;
}
```

In your delete_alt, you need to do this:

```
while (previous !=NULL && current != NULL) {
    previous->link = current->link; 
    next = current->link;
    free(current);
    if(next) {
      next->prev = previous;
      current = next->link;
    }
    else current = NULL;
    previous = next;
}
```

Try it here: https://repl.it/HK2P/0